# Solving a specific loop

Tags: prolog

```
near(a1,b1).    near(b1,c1).    near(c1,d1).    near(d1,e1).    near(e1,f1).
near(f1,g1).    near(a1,a2).    near(a2,a3).    near(a3,a4).    near(a4,a5).
near(a5,a6).    near(a6,a7).    near(a7,a8).    near(a8,a9).    near(b1,b2).
near(b2,b3).    near(b3,b4).    near(b4,b5).    near(b5,b6).    near(b6,b7).
near(b7,b8).    near(b8,b9).    near(c4,d4).    near(d1,e4).    near(e4,f4).
near(f4,g4).    near(g4,h4).    near(g1,g2).    near(g2,g3).    near(g3,g4).
near(f4,f5).    near(f5,f6).    near(f6,f7).    near(f7,f8).    near(f8,f9).
near(a6,b6).    near(b6,c6).    near(a9,b9).    near(b9,c9).    near(c9,d9).
near(d9,f9).    near(f9,g9).    near(g9,h9).    near(h9,i9).

path(X,X).
path(X,Y):-
   near(X,Z), path(Z,Y),
   write(X),
   write('->'),
   write(Z).

maze(X,Y):-findall(X,path(X,Y),Path_List),write(Path_List).
```

This is finding way maze.

I want print out like this

```
 Route1 [18] a1 -> b1 -> c1 -> d1 -> e1 -> f1 -> g1 -> g2 -> g3 -> g4 -> h4 -> h5 -> h6 -> h7 -> h8 -> h9 -> i9
```

and showing other 4 Routes.

I think using cut? or Backtracking. But i can't touch this code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, writing out the intermediate steps that a backtracking algorithm takes to actually solve a problem is a *very* useless technique. Most of the output produced by path/2 second clause is 'noise'.

This is also the motivation that leads to trace/0 as primary debug tool for Prolog. Traces carry *additional* information, like the nesting level, that is *indispensable* to make sense of the output.

Then I would suggest to get rid of write(s) in path/2, add an argument 'carrying back' the path, and write a service predicate to print:

```
path(X,X, [X]).
path(X,Y, [X|Cs]):-
    near(X,Z), path(Z,Y, Cs).

maze(X,Y):- forall(path(X,Y,Ps),writeln(Ps)).

?- maze(a1,i9).
[a1,b1,c1,d1,e4,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,g9,h9,i9]
[a1,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,c9,d9,f9,g9,h9,i9]
[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,b9,c9,d9,f9,g9,h9,i9]
[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,b6,b7,b8,b9,c9,d9,f9,g9,h9,i9]
true.
```

not very attractive, but surely more useful.

Note that path/3 (as well as path/2) *will loop forever* in presence of loops...

*edit* using [pqGraphviz](https://github.com/CapelliC/loqt/tree/master/pqGraphviz), this snippet

```
maze_g(X,Y) :-
    graph_window(maze_g(X,Y),[]).

maze_g(X,Y,G) :-
    forall(path(X,Y,Ns),
        (maplist(make_node(G),Ns,Ps)
        ,nodes_chain(Ps,Cs)
        ,make_edges(G,Cs))).
```

followed by `?- maze_g(a1,i9).`, yields

[image: a basic pqGraphviz rendering all paths]